# Variable of required type was not provided

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo

I am attempting to create a relationship in my Neo4j database with a GraphQL mutation. I have a number of other mutations already working except this one causing problems. It looks like this:

```
mutation(
    $id: String!,
    $recipe: String!,
    $date: String!
) {
    CreateUserRecipeRelation(id:$id, recipe:$recipe, date:$date) {
            id
        recipe {
        name
      }
  }    
}
```

I am passing in the following set of parameters:

```
{"id": "google-oauth2|yyyyremovedauthstuffyyyy", "recipe": "baked spaghetti", "date": "10/10/2018"}
```

But the GraphQL playground throws the following error:

"Variable \"$id\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided."

In my schema.graphql file I have the following defined:

```
  CreateUserRecipeRelation (
    id: String
    recipe: String
    date: String
  ): User @cypher(statement:
    "MATCH (r:Recipe{name:$recipe}), (u:User{id:$id}) CREATE (r)-[c:Created_By{date:$date}]->(u) RETURN r,c,u")
```

And if I run that cypher query directly in Neo4j it works just fine. In this same project I have 5 or 6 other relationship-creating mutations currently working but this one is giving me pause.

UPDATE:

This is a mutation I currently have that is working, so you can see the similarity in structure:

```
  CreateIngredientRelation (
    name: String
    recipe: String
    quantity: String
  ): Ingredient @cypher(statement:
    "MATCH (r:Recipe{name:$recipe}), (i:Ingredient{name:$name}) CREATE (r)-[c:Contains{quantity:$quantity}]->(i) RETURN r,c,i")
```

This one works great and creates tons of relationships with the quantity attached to them. This is why I am puzzled. If they both didn't work it would be easier to try and come up with a solution I think.

Comment: No follow up on how you resolved this question, if you did?

Comment: You know, I don't remember if I solved it. I imagine I did. Let me check my repo this evening and see what fixes I put in place and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

@BehemothDan, how are you calling this mutation? Are you using `react-apollo`? If yes, Let me provide you an example of how you should be handling this.
For example, if you have a form to create this `UserRecipeRelation`. You have your `Mutation` component from `react-apollo`. On this `Mutation` you have on `renderProps` `CreateUserRecipeRelation`, that you could pass to a function on `onSubmit`. In this function you pass your variables:

`UserRecipeRelation({ variables: { id: 'your id', recipe: 'bla bla', date: '12/12/18'  } });`

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I am indeed using Apollo. I will reformat my variables how you are suggesting and see if that works. I do recall seeing an example in that format during some reading. It is weird that I have another mutation I am calling in almost the exact same format (three variables with one being a property on the relationship) that works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, check that and return here later :)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I have tried to move outside of my react components, and get it to work within GraphQL Playground and it still throws the same error. I am going to edit my post with one of my mutations that is working properly that shares the format.

Comment: @BehemothDan, something that you could try:
Your `id` should be my opinion the type `ID!` instead of `String`. Give a try on this, maybe this id of yours is not being passed or dealt as a string.

Comment: Willing to give it a shot. I definitely like the idea of not having it be a string like all the other data types. Thanks for the suggestion.